# How to push items into the controller array using a form with input fields and that will show up in the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.2/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.2"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="module in validation.modules">Title:{{module.title}}
    description:{{module.description}}</div>
    <div>
      <form name="myForm" novalidate class="simple-form">
    Title:  <input value="" type="text" placeholder="a" ng-model="itemAmount"><br />
    description: <input value="" type="text" placeholder="Name of Item" ng-model="itemName">
    <br />
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add to list</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.validation = {
    "modules":
        [
                {
                   "title":"name of validation1",
                   "description":"description of validation1"

                },

                {
                   "title":"name of validation2",
                   "description":"description of validation2"

                }
        ]
  };
   $scope.addItem = function () {
            $scope.validation.modules.push({
            title: $scope.itemAmount,
            description: $scope.itemName
        });
    };
});
```

The below file is a pluknr in which i am just binding using ng-model to display

> http://plnkr.co/edit/5NXHQiOApzNU5cn0yQT2

My Question is that you can see in the plunker file that there is a add to list button .. what i want to do is that i want to add a pop up tab like the one you can see in the MODAL section in the below link

> https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

and add some text fields to it let's suppose a form and when i click add to list in the pop up form i want it to be added in the view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

http://plnkr.co/edit/nI6PhjbAKEdTgXeWMKDx?p=preview

Opening the modal in main controller and handling the result from modal:

```
$scope.openModal = function() {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl : 'myModal.html',
            controller: 'myModalController'
        })

  modalInstance.result.then(function(info) {
    console.log(info);
    $scope.validation.modules.push(info);
  })
```

Binding data into modal controller:

```
app.controller('myModalController', function($scope, $modalInstance) {
  $scope.infoToAdd = {
    title: "",
    description: ""
  }

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.infoToAdd);
  }

  $scope.cancel = function() {
    $modalInstance.dismiss("cancel");
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModal.html">
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
Title:  <input type="text" placeholder="Title" ng-model="infoToAdd.title"><br />
description: <input type="text" placeholder="Description" ng-model="infoToAdd.description">
<br />
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addItem()">Add to list</button>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</script>
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote / select this as the right answer if it helped you :)